# How to access EXCEL fields in AngularJS which are including spaces

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel

I have an excel where I should read data and save the values in to database. When trying to read the value from EXCEL column fields it throws an error:

> unidentified name.

Below is the format of my excel:

- User Data -> I should omit the header
- User Name User Phone Number -> Trim spaces between the columns.

  ```
  //controller.js
  function userData() {
     angular.forEach(vm.readUserData, function(userInfo){
         userInfo.userName=userInfo.User Name; //not reading the column value from an EXCELbecause of spaces.
     });
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try access your attribute like this and you will be fine:

```
userInfo.userName = userInfo['User Name'];
```

Comment: Hi lin i tried your logic it still cannot read the field name.

Comment: Please add the object `userInfo` to your question.

Comment: Hi Lin couldn't understand what do you mean by adding object userInfo?

Comment: @GrailsLearner Please add the object content of `userInfo` where you try to access the attribute `User Name`.

Comment: Hi lin your solution worked when i removed the main header.Now i should think whether to omit the main header or is there any other way where i can read the data by keeping the main header too.